# programmatic wiki

Tags: programming, wiki, desktop-client

I am searching for software for a wiki platform. The program should be programatic, i.e. a smart way of storing all posts in files on disk that can be edited and checked into git. I also want it to be a heavy client with no network connections and it should rely heavily on mnemonics to allow quick and easy browsing of multiple posts.

Does anyone know of software like this, or would I have to develop it on my own?